# What's the best way to go to Barcelona from Madrid?

Tags: barcelona, madrid, summer

What's the best way to get to Barcelona from Madrid?

Comment: Hi, 'best way' evokes opinions and we're not very good at opinions.  Please edit your question so that it specifies cheap, fast, or practical and so on.  Even time of day makes a difference in the best way of getting from Madrid to Barcelona.  Try to be as specific as possible and you will get some high quality answers.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Go by train.

I took the AVE high speed train from Barcelona (Estacio De França) to Madrid (Atocha).

IMO, it is the best way to travel between the 2 cities.

i takes around 4 hours, the stations are easily accessible, you do not have to come in early, go through lots of security and you have a lot less restriction in bagage size and weight.